# Trouble reading a Float32Array back out as part of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

In my Electron app I am trying to write some text data, followed by a Float32Array, into a file, and then read it back out. The following code works as expected:

```
fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, audioBuffer);

// Later
const contentBuffer = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath);
let audioBuffer = new Float32Array(contentBuffer.buffer); // audioBuffer contains the correct length and contents
```

The trouble starts when I prepend the buffer with some additional text.

```
fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, "test" + audioBuffer);

// Later
const contentBuffer = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath);
```

From here I have tried several different approaches, but they either result in `RangeError`s or nonsense arrays. Some of my attempts:

```
let audioBuffer = new Float32Array(contentBuffer.buffer, 4);
```

```
let slice = contentBuffer.slice(4);
let audioBuffer = new Float32Array(slice.buffer);
```

```
let contents = contentBuffer.toString('utf-8');
let audioBufferString = contents.substring(4);
let buffer = Buffer.from(audioBufferString, 'utf-8');
let audioBuffer = new Float32Array(buffer);
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I don't see it.

Comment: `fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, "test" + audioBuffer);` are you using `await` here in your application?

Comment: Yes, the reading occurs in a completely separate function; I just put them side by side here for ease of reading. I'll edit in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I *thought* the `string + Float32Array` was being handled correctly, but it wasn't. What works is creating a buffer from the string, and then concatenating it with the array, like so.

```
let jsonBuffer = Buffer.from("test");
fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, Buffer.concat([jsonBuffer, audioBuffer]));

// Later
let audioBuffer = new Float32Array(contentBuffer.buffer, 4, (contentBuffer.byteLength - 4) / 4);
```

Of course the byteOffset is hard-coded here and care needs to be taken to make sure the array is stored at an aligned position, but that was all easy enough to add.